# Stopping Invokation of Spring Quartz Job on spring context loading

Tags: spring, quartz-scheduler

My application has got multiple Jobs which needs to be executed programatically when user wants.

I have implemented all the Jobs using MethodInvokingJobFactoryBean and the issue is whenever my spring context gets loads up all the Jobs gets fired.

How to stop the execution of Job on spring context loading ??

Thanks in advance
Ajay

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have problem because your job calls beans which has not been initialized?

Then you will be interested in **depends-on** attribute on bean element.

You can also set **startupDelay** property on **SchedulerFactoryBean**.